# Is there an node.js http equivalent for XMLHttpRequest.readyState?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest

With Javascript's XMLHttpRequest object, there is a property called [readyState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState) that is very often used in tandem with the response codes to check if an HTTP request has finished before processing other code.

```
 if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
   // Do stuff
 }
```

With Node.js's [http module](https://nodejs.dev/learn/the-nodejs-http-module#httpserverresponse) you can [make HTTP requests](https://nodejs.dev/learn/making-http-requests-with-nodejs) and retrieve status codes, just like the XMLHttpRequest object.

```
if (`${res.statusCode}` == 200) {
  //Do things
}
```

However, does the http module have any equivalent of the "readyState" property that the XMLHttpRequest object has? I can't seem to find any documentation for it anywhere, but I want to make sure that I am only running the next code after the sent request has fully finished and not when it's half-done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `res.on('end', callback)` to run whenever the response is fully completed, passing a callback to handle the response when completed.

In this case, take an example of a huge image. It proceeds to the end when all the chunks are retrieved and then, right after it, the callback is called.

```js
const http = require('http')
const options = {
     host: 'placekitten.com',
     path: '/5000/2500'
} 

http.get(options, (res) => {
     let code = res.statusCode
     console.log("Got response: " + code)
     res.on('data', chunk => console.log("Data received"))
     res.on('end', () => {
          if (code === 200) {
               console.log("Sent request has fully finished")
          } else {
               console.log("Code wasn't 200!")
          }
     })
}).on('error', function(e) {
     console.log("Got error: " + e.message)
})
```

Place this code [here](https://www.katacoda.com/courses/nodejs/playground) to try on a live server.

Comment: Great, thank you! If I were to use `https.request()` instead of [`http.get()`](https://nodejs.dev/learn/the-nodejs-http-module#httpget) and on an
`http.ServerResponse` check if the status code is 200, would that be the equivalent of using `res.on('end'. callback)`? Or without the `.on(end...)` are we not guaranteed that the response is fully completed, even with a 200 status code? (I.e. could some of the chunks of the huge image still be in the process of being sent even though the status code is 200?)

Comment: If you're gonna use `req = http.request(options, callback)` then it's the same thing regarding to `res.on('end',callback)`. However, if you use the latter, as the docs says: *"... (you) must always call `req.end()` to signify the end of the request - even if there is no data being written to the request body."* Note that `res.on('end')` and `req.end()` are different methods